# How do I interpret a contingency table?

Tags: r, contingency

In this result (see the link of picture) of cross tabulation, I don't understand ONLY a number marked in red. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWGjb.jpg

I would be very grateful for the explanation!

This table received in R with 'CrossTable(data$status, data$gender)'.

P.S. "add more context..." Details are clear from the picture

JorgeAmVF, thanks for correcting my text! )

Comment: Please add more context around your question: Code sample of how you obtain the table, small data sample, also it would be clearer to copy paste the text as code rather than image. Thanks.